# Uploading files using Angular/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, upload

I have a client built in Angular. I am trying to upload files that are to be processed by the asp.net server side code. Although I have managed to get files in the file control but I don't know how I can pass the binary data to server side. My client side code looks as follows

HTML Code

```
<div>
<form name="form1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        {{repopulatecftcModel.title}}
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;"><b>Toolkit - Repopulate Cftc Data</b></div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="updCftcFileUploader" name="files[]" multiple />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Upload Files" title="Upload Files" ng-click="UploadCFTCFiles()" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label ng-model="repopulatecftc.validationtext"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{repopulatecftcModel.validationtext}}
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller Code in Angular

```
function controller($scope, $http, AppModel, WebFunctionService) {

        $scope.UploadFiles = function (evt) {

            var files = document.getElementById('updFileUploader').files;
            for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                if (file) {
                    //  getAsText(file);
                    alert("Name: " + file.name + "\n" + "Last Modified Date :" + file.lastModifiedDate);
                }
            }
            var parameters = { directory: $scope.defaultsSaveDirectory, filename: "" };
            WebFunctionService.promiseWebMethod('UploadFiles', angular.fromJson(parameters), true)
                .success(function () {
                    $scope.userMessage = "File(s) successfully uploaded";
                    console.log($scope.userMessage);
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.userMessage = "ERROR uploading files" + error;
                    console.log($scope.userMessage);
                });

        };

    };
```

Server side code where I want to access the uploaded files from

```
[Route("UploadFiles")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void UploadFiles()
    {

    }
```

When I run the code I do get alerts for each of the file being uploaded. Then the code get into the server side as shown in the image below

[image: Server side code]

Its here that I want to access the files from. I have seen in the web where they show Request.Files shows the collection of files being uploaded but when I try to do that the compiler starts complaining.

[image: Compiler error when using Request.Files]

Anyone have any clues as to how I should be able to pass binary data being uploaded from client side in this case and access it from the server side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In angular when you call the server side you can use $upload to upload a file here is an example:

```
 var uploadFile = function (file, args) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $upload.upload({
            url: "<your url goes here>",
            method: "POST",
            file: file,
            data: args
        }).progress(function (evt) {
            // get upload percentage
            console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // file is uploaded successfully
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // file failed to upload
            deferred.reject();
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

The above function will pass the file along with extra args if you need it.

Server side

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddFile()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/temp/uploads");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // On upload, files are given a generic name like "BodyPart_26d6abe1-3ae1-416a-9429-b35f15e6e5d5"
        // so this is how you can get the original file name
        var originalFileName = GetDeserializedFileName(result.FileData.First());

        var uploadedFileInfo = new FileInfo(result.FileData.First().LocalFileName);
        string path = result.FileData.First().LocalFileName;

        //Do whatever you want to do with your file here

        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, originalFileName );
    }

    private string GetDeserializedFileName(MultipartFileData fileData)
    {
        var fileName = GetFileName(fileData);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fileName).ToString();
    }

    public string GetFileName(MultipartFileData fileData)
    {
        return fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
    }
```

Comment: It did answer my original question in terms of passing file from angular client to server side code so marked it as correct